# How to match mongodb query between fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

let's say i have a collection:

```
{ id: 0, likes: 1},
{ id: 1, likes: 0},
// ^ it's match
{ id: 2, likes: 0},
{ id: 3, likes: 0}
```

*likes column is refeer to id column who will be match.
we know that id:0 match with id:1 because id:0 like id:1, and id:0 like id:1. To find that with query i'm using this:

**Existing Solution but Cause App Crash**

```
session_store = req.session
User.find({ likes: session_store.id }, (err, data1) => {

    for (user of data1) {
      var idWhoLikesIdSession = user.id

      User.find({
        id: idWhoLikesIdSession,
        likes: session_store.id
      }, (err, data2) => {
        res.json(data2)
      })
    }

})
```

That's actually works, but User.find in for-loop cause app crash and session been reset. I need new solution.

Help me, thank you.

Comment: You can't use _res.json_ more than once.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I want to point out you should be aware that MongoDB / NoSQL is not well suited for relational database design. It's okay to have denormalized data when using MongoDB.

1. Since you haven't provided a error message / reason why it has crashed it's hard to say what was actually causing it in the first place.
2. Your desired "new" solution: What you are most likely looking for is `populate()` which does a join-like lookup in your query. Therefore you got to designe a reference in your mongoose schemas. Check the mongoose documentation: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

**Edit:** As of your issue TGrif already told you one in the comments why your solution can't work. You are iterating in a for loop (which would run multiple `User.find()` and in each response you are trying to send a response (`res.json()`). This would most likely throw exceptions like:

> Response headers have already been sent